# Why is this C++ money_put<char> program not working?

Tags: c++, localization, internationalization, locale

I am experimenting with C++ locales, and cannot work out why the output is `0.05` instead of `4.98`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {


    vector<string> locales;
    locales.push_back("de_DE");
    locales.push_back("en_AU");
    locales.push_back("en_GB");
    locales.push_back("zh_CN");

    long double amount = 4.98;
    for (size_t i = 0, s = locales.size(); i < s; ++i) {
        if (locales[i] != "C") {
            cout.imbue(locale(locales[i].c_str()));
            cout << i << " (" << locales[i] << "): ";

            const moneypunct<char>& mp = use_facet<moneypunct<char> >(cout.getloc());
            const money_put<char>& mv = use_facet<money_put<char> >(cout.getloc());

            cout << mp.curr_symbol();
            ostreambuf_iterator<char> out(cout);
            mv.put(out, false, cout, cout.fill(), amount);
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is below:

```
0 (de_DE): Eu0,05
1 (en_AU): $0.05
2 (en_GB): £0.05
3 (zh_CN): ￥0.05
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because `amount` is set to 4.98.

Answer (score 3):

The (simplified) answer is that the `money_put<char>.put()` function refers to a `long double` parameter called `units`. This is the units in *cents*, not *dollars*.

Answer (score 1):

[locale.money.put.virtuals]

The argument `units` is transformed into a sequence of wide characters as if by

```
ct.widen(buf1, buf1 + sprintf(buf1, "%.0Lf", units), buf2)
```

You can find exhaustive info on the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/money_put/put) page.